# Holding clutch when braking

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, braking

I always hold my clutch when braking suddenly in traffic or to move in traffic. I heard that its bad driving. I tried to stop holding clutch and I am unsuccessful in it. How bad is this for motorcycle?. Any tip on not to hold clutch when braking?.

Comment: Where did you read its bad driving ? Please add the reference

Comment: @VijayMaximOff sorry I heard not read. Changed it

Comment: This is a driving question and may be considered off topic and deleted as a result.  If you change the question to being bad for the motorcycle it may be considered on topic.  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Come by chat sometime if you would like to debate your driving issue.   :-)   Thanks for question but unfortunately it's off topic unless you modify it so it can remain open.    http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here's a great video critiquing various braking and downshifting techniques.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrbZJbXwgrY

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**why using your clutch during braking can be considered unsafe**

I have ridden motorcycles for years.  Engine braking is a component of safe riding.

The engine itself can be ok and not receive any damage from pulling in the clutch while breaking other than it is additional wear on throw out bearing for the pressure plate within the clutch.

***The throwout bearing is number 6 in the image below.***

[image]

Although pulling in your clutch may not harm your engine it can lead to instability when breaking.

Under braking the rotational mass of the engine has a gyroscopic effect and assists in keeping the motorcycle upright.  Pulling in the clutch takes away from the gyroscopic effect and may make the motorcycle feel unstable.

Rather than pulling in the clutch you can downshift immediately while using the front brake and allow the engine to slow the rear wheel and provide additional gyroscopic effect for more stability under panic stops.  The resistance of the road on the rear wheel will assist in providing stability as well and an indication if the rear wheel has lifted off the ground from over braking on the front.

If you were to lock up your rear wheel by using your rear brake AND pull in your clutch thereby reducing the gyroscopic effect of one wheel and the motor the bike could become very unstable.  You would only have the gyroscopic effect of the front wheel and it's a very strange feeling as you travel at a high rate of speed yet feel like tipping over.

**Engine braking under normal braking helps to provide stability.**

Comment: "Rather than pulling in the clutch you can downshift immediately while using the front brake.......", does this mean we can downshift without pulling the clutch ?

Comment: oh I didn't know this so far. Thanks for clarifying @DucatiKiller

Comment: Will this apply to cars?

Comment: @Nanoc Obviously keeping a car upright isn't a factor, but otherwise, yes, this applies to cars as well. In a car, wheel lock-up is usually less serious, but will increase the stopping distance.

Comment: @DucatiKiller I'm far from an expert here, but I took a safe riding course, and the emergency breaking procedure was this one: Completely pull clutch, progressively apply both front and back brakes; the back one being safe to lock it, but not the front one. I experimented this breaking procedure and to me it felt a lot safer than downshifting, because the bike is a lot stabler if you also need to dodge an obstacle. So I don't really agree with your answer...

Comment: I'm with @AlinPurcaru... Unless you lock your wheels, you're not losing any "gyroscopic" effect... that comes directly from the rotational inertia of the wheels. And while you can shift without the clutch (and it is considerably easier on most motorcycles than on any modern car), I'd consider that more of an intermediate/advanced technique, which could be potentially dangerous in a panic situation for a less-skilled rider. I think having control over the brakes is much easier than landing a clutchless downshift with the perfect rev-match so as to not induce any shock into the drivetrain.

Comment: ...In addition, I strongly doubt the rotational mass of the engine (i.e. the flywheel) contributes any significant gyroscopic effects, compared to the wheels.

Comment: Provide your citation then.    Have you seen a dirtbike change angles in the air?  Is that from magic or physics?

Comment: Think of a bicycle wheel spinning and you have the axle in your hands.  It's going at about 300 RPM and weighs about 2.5 kilograms.  When you try and turn the wheel off it's axis it resists.  The force is unusually strong and a bit shocking the first time you do it.  Now think of a 150 kilo crankshaft spinning at 5,000 to 10,000 RPM.  How much force do you think that has.  When you counter steer a motorcycle into a corner the force resisting the handlebar is a gyroscopic force.  When your pushing into the corner, that's mostly the force of the crankshaft you are working against.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru  I respect your opinion.  I've been riding all my life.  I've taught new riders, my son and I both road raced for years.  Read Keith Codes' "A Twist of the Wrist" and get back to me on pulling in your clutch under breaking.  It's considered dangerous.  There's a reason why most vehicles in motorsports use engine breaking on the rear wheel, it's for stability.  Respectfully.

Comment: @Shamtam - I'd have to say, it sounds as though you are contradicting yourself. You say you agree with Alin Purcaru, but then you say "Unless you are locking your wheels", which is exactly what Alin is suggesting. Not both, but the rear. I'm pretty sure you'll lose the gyroscopic effect of the rear wheel if you lock it up. I think there is a lot of opinion in these comments, where Ducati has the practical experience of many years of riding. I respect people's opinions, but I trust Ducati's experience.

Comment: It's the physics.  A super heavy shaft spinning at thousands of RPM's.  Gyroscopic effect.  Break hard from 90mph downshifting all the way and then do it with just your front brake.  The bike can begin to feel out of control and find yourself steering and shifting your weight around to stay straight while breaking super hard.  Nooooooooo!   You downshift and grab tons of front and feel in control...and downshifting.  OMG.  Are we really having this conversation?

Comment: @AlinPurcaru  Here's a good video on gyroscopic effect with a good kicker on angular momentum.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ty9QSiVC2g0

Comment: @AlinPurcaru   Here's a great video critiquing various downshifting and braking techniques.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrbZJbXwgrY

Answer (score 3):

Holding the clutch while braking can make the rear wheel more likely to lock-up. Also you lose the additional engine braking.

Comment: Indeed it's true, then you get that nice rear wheel hop when you lock it up on light bikes like these.